# How to Run PeerJS Server Heroku Once Installed

Tags: heroku, peerjs

I have got my PeerJS Server Installed on Heroku.

When I run the test page `myappname.herokuapp.com` in my web browser it responds:

```
{"name":"PeerJS Server","description":"A server side element to broker connections between PeerJS clients.","website":"https://peerjs.com/"}
```

However, how do I run the command?

```
$ peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /myapp
```

What is  `myapp` ?

As it presently stands, when I try to connect to my Heroku PeerJS Server from a webpage, it just says it cannot generate an id.

I try to call it within my html page with:

```
const peer = new Peer(null /*'someid'*/, {
                host: "myappname.herokuapp.com/",
                port: 443,
                path: '/myapp',
                secure: true,
            });
```

Again, I do not know what `myapp` is?

Do I have to generate my own ids? I though that was done on the Heroku Server?

And how do I generate my own ids? What file do I alter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, how do I run the command?
>
> ```
> peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /myapp
> ```

You don't.

I assume you have deployed PeerJS using the "Deploy to Heroku" button [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/peers/peerjs-server).
In that case, you don't have to run the command. The server is already running.

Some more info:

Heroku is a hosting platform. It allows you to host *applications* written in Node.js (and some other languages).
When you clicked the "Deploy to Heroku" button, all the setup for PeerJS was done automatically behind the scenes.

https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started is an example app that is built to run on Heroku.
I would highly recommend going through the step-by-step tutorial and setup the example app:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prepare-the-app

---

> What is myapp ?

`myapp` is the *url path* that PeerJS will listen on.
The way you have it setup, PeerJS will run on the root url (`https://myappname.herokuapp.com`). As you noticed, just visiting the website will give you the test JSON message.

But what if you want your website to be displayed when someone opens `https://myappname.herokuapp.com`, and still want to host PeerJS on the same server? In that case, you can tell PeerJS to only listen to requests on the (for example) `https://myappname.herokuapp.com/myapp` url. That way, a normal visitor will see your website on visiting the url, and your website can still use PeerJS at `https://myappname.herokuapp.com/myapp`.

Since we know that the host of the server (`https://myappname.herokuapp.com`) will remain the same, we only need to tell PeerJS the *relative path* on which it has to listen.

Note that the url path is not limited to one subdirectory. You should be able to use `/peerjs`, `/services/peerjs`, `/a/b/c` or any other valid path.

---

> As it presently stands, when I try to connect to my Heroku PeerJS Server from a webpage, > it just says it cannot generate an id.
>
> I try to call it within my html page with:
>
> ```js
> const peer = new Peer(null /*'someid'*/, {
>             host: "myappname.herokuapp.com/",
>             port: 443,
>             path: '/myapp',
>             secure: true,
>        });
> ```

I suspect the error is because of the incorrect parameters.

Let us go over them again:

- Passing in `null` as the id is not a good idea, try using a string like `"someid"`
- `host` should be `myappname.herokuapp.com`, the trailing slash (`/`) might cause issues
- `port` is correct, but not required since it defaults to `443`
  (`443` is the standard HTTPS port).
- `path` is incorrect in this case, since the PeerJS server is running on the root url
  this parameter should be ommited
- `secure` is correct, Heroku apps run on HTTPS.

Here are the PeerJS client docs for reference: https://peerjs.com/docs.html#peer-options

Try using this code to connect to your PeerJS instance:

```js
const peer = new Peer("someid", {
    host: "myappname.herokuapp.com",
    secure: true
});
```

I have tried to explain terms as much as I could, but please feel free to ask if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. OK, so if I chose to run PeerJS Server on my Winhost website in a subdomain, then something would be different. So say my subdomain was `mypeerjs.mywebsite.com` I can unzip the PeerJS Server code in my subdomain. **BUT** how would I get it running on Port 90 of my Winhost subdomain? (Port 90 is the one available to me on my Winhost account.)

Comment: If your code can receive requests from `mypeerjs.mywebsite.com` then you need to change the start command to `peerjs --port 90`, and the client config to `const peer = new Peer("id", {host: "mypeerjs.mywebsite.com", port: 90, secure: true})`. From what I could tell, WinHost is using some kind of IIS plugin. If you have the option then I would recommend using a service like Heroku, since it is much easier to setup.
I personally have never used WinHost, so the only advice I can give you is to contact support.

Comment: I have tried all the things you said first of all I would say very well explained I understood many things yet my app is not able to connect with heroku peerjs is it possible I have missed any steps?

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi Thanks. Can you double-check if you are using the same configuration as in the question, and that you have not missed a step? If not, then would you mind creating a new question with your exact setup and posting the link here, since that will be easier to debug.

Comment: So I actually fixed the problem I saw in some other article then only I noticed In host I kept this whole thing "https://myappname.herokuapp.com" whereas I should keep only this "myappname.herokuapp.com" its completely my mistake so now its fixed